# How do I realize a client-server model?

Tags: android, ruby, amazon-web-services, jruby

A client is application in android wrote on JRuby. A server is a Ruby on Rails application at AwS. Client should download a data, show the data, manage the data, store the data. Client is not one and connecting trough Internet. Server download the data with web page, shows status of client and manage client with web page.

How do I organize the communication between client and server on ruby and jruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Server-App is a Rail, it should support a RESTful Interface just fine (if you implemented it properly).

In your Client, you may use ActiveResource to interact with that Server easily.

**EDIT:**

there is even a railscast about it http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics
Think of your JRuby-Client as a small Rails-App, and stuff will work ;)